# Statute of limitations for F on M rape across jurisdictions?

Tags: australia, rape, hong-kong

I am an Aussie dude (ie, a person with a penis, pronouns "him, he, his"). Back in 2015/16 I was living in Hong Kong, engaged to a local girl (ie someone with a vagina, tits and womb) 2 years older than me.

The entire relationship was just her abusing me and manipulating me (I was a young naive guy).

Now, specifically for this question,  she raped me regularly. It was rape because I did not consent before during or after, I communicated this to her clearly and repeatedly, but she just kept doing it. At the time I thought it was my fault and so the trauma was amplified by an intense experience of catholic guilt, dread and despair. She was able to keep doing it to me for a variety of complicated reasons, but one simple reason was that I had to take a high dose of epilim and zeldox every night, which I'm fairly sure means i was "incapable of consent" under aussie law at least.

So, the actual question: Is it worth taking her to court over this, and how would that work given that im in australia and she's in HK? not gonna lie, im not looking for money; i'd be happy even if it were possible to simply blacklist her passport and prevent her from entering australia, or get her name logged on a sex offenders registry in hong kong or something. Im still suffering and recovering from this 4 years on, whereas she got away without any consequences; what legal rights to compensation could i perhaps pursue here?

Comment: A more reliable answer/assitance is more likely to be found at such Organisations:
[Australia: Sexual Abuse Counselling | Life Supports Counselling](https://lifesupportscounselling.com.au/specialist-areas/sexual-abuse-counselling/), that have more **practical experience** in how to deal with such situations. This would include also any legal options available.

Comment: Man, I’m sorry... :(

Answer (score 6):

This occurred in Hong Kong, so Hong Kong law applies here.

Hong Kong law's definition of rape is explicitly male on female (nonconsensual male-male is covered by sodomy laws instead). It is impossible for her to be charged with rape.

Assuming you were over 16 at the time, the only offence that could be possible is indecent assault. As far as I can tell, there is no statute of limitations. However, the chance of her being charged is basically zero.